# How to handle dates in cx_oracle using python?

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I'm trying to access Oracle table using cx_oracle module and convert that as a dataframe, every thing is fine except couple of date columns has date format like "01-JAN-01"  Python considering it as datetime.datetime(1,1,1,0,0) and after creating dataframe it's showing as 0001-01-01 00:00:00. I am expecting output as 2001-01-01 00:00:00. Please help me on this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of choices. You could
* Retrieve it from the Oracle database with [read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html specifying the date in a format (`TO_CHAR`) more appropriate for the default date format of pandas
* Retrieve it from the database as a string (as above) and then convert it into a date in the pandas framework.